# Should I try to get an old late credit card payment removed?

Tags: credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

I have a Capital One credit card that had a "$40 Maximum Delinquency of 30 days in 2011". It was paid after 30 days in 2011 and was a simple mistake from an annual auto renew charge for a website hosting company. I haven't used that card in a couple of years. Should I call capital one and seeing if they'll remove that? If so what is the best way to go about it (e.g. phonecall, letter, both)? Or is it best to leave it alone because it might renew something or cause them to cancel that credit card that is my oldest line of credit and hasn't been actually used since that payment in 2011?

Comment: Whose mistake was it? Yours or the website hosting company?

Comment: one option is to contest it(online) with the credit agency. The reporting entity may not respond in time, which removes it by default.

Comment: It was my fault. I was set up for auto renew every year and I totally forgot. The CC had nothing charged for over 6 months before that charge went through so I had totally forgot to check it.

Comment: Cap1 might remove it since you've been such a loyal customer, can't hurt to ask. There would be no reason for them to take negative action against you for asking

Comment: Have you pulled your credit report to ensure that this late payment was even reported?  I had a situation once where I forgot to pay a card before I left for a trip, I came home to a late fee but it was never actually reported as late.

Answer (score 3):

Since it was a mistake on your part, it may be difficult to have it removed from your credit report. Late payments take 7 years to drop of credit reports, and since you are 4 years in, it may make more sense just to leave it alone, as the simple act of contesting it could cause the clock to reset.

Answer (score 2):

Your credit report is supposed to be an accurate reflection of what has happened in your credit history.   It is accurately reflecting that you were late so to file a dispute would be a form of fraud.   You would be attesting that what was written was incorrect when you know that it is not.